# How can I check if a job is buildable or not with Java

Tags: java, hudson, jobs

I just want to check if a job is buildable or not in Java. I tried with the following code. But I can't find the `.isbuildable()` function with "project."

```
for(TopLevelItem project : hudson.model.Hudson.getInstance().getView("VIEW>").getItems() { 
    String projectName = project.getFullDisplayName(); 
    //project. bla bla bla
    ...
}
```

But if I type the following code I can find the function. But I don't know how to implement or get the right librarys for the second code line.

```
boolean jobbuildable;
Job<Job<JobT,RunT>, Run<JobT,RunT>> jobname;
jobbuildable = jobname.isBuildable();
```

Do you know how to find out if a job on Jenkins is buildable or not?

Comment: What do you mean by buildable?

Comment: A `TopLevelItem` is not a `Job`. https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/TopLevelItem.java http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/TopLevelItem.html

Comment: With buildable I mean a job, which can be builded/started(Schedule a build) by a user. Sometimes a user has no permission to build a job, he just can read it. And I need to differ between a buildable and a none buildable job...

Comment: Can somebody help me please? :-)